# Xamarin Forms ios application System.IO.FileNotFoundException while debugging on iphone device

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, asset-catalog

I used asset catolog on xamarin ios app.I debug project on iphone simulator and there was no error. But while I was debugging on iphone device in Visual studio. The project get error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   /Users/merverogop/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Mobil.iOS/aa2888bd11ecba5d622060c89aa4abc7/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/actool/bundle/LaunchImage.png
>   does not exist File name:
>   '/Users/merverogop/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Mobil.iOS/aa2888bd11ecba5d622060c89aa4abc7/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/actool/bundle/LaunchImage.png'
>   at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String
>   destFileName, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x00193] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:111
>   at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.CopyFile (System.String
>   source, System.String target, System.String targetItemSpec) [0x0002d]
>   in <005c894bac3b423fb04b2601188910b5>:0    at
>   Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.Execute () [0x00108] in
>   <005c894bac3b423fb04b2601188910b5>:0  Mobil.iOS

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. problems reason is image in resources folder. I used different image and delete launchImage.png. Error is gone.