# Xamarin iOS build creates blank icons that cause build error

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

When I build a Xamarin.Forms it creates a set of blank icons in

\obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\actool\bundle

and

\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\DaemonDictionary.iOS.app

The app works in the emulator but when I try to deploy to an iPhone I get a 'Could not find file' error for one of the icons that was created in the build. I cannot find any reference to the generated .png files anywhere in my projects so I don't know where they are coming from. They all have 0KB for their file size. I have an Assets.xcassets file for my actual app icons and they all work in the various iPhone and iPad emulators.

I have attached an image of the generated icons to show the names. [generated icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy35P.jpg)

Are these icons being created during the build process? I haven't found any docs that say the icons in my Assets.xcassets must have specific filenames, but is that the case? Is there a config or settings file somewhere in my solution / project that is making the build process create them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Based on the name `AppIcon`, see [Application Icons in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons). Perhaps if you explicitly create an `AppIcon` image set, as mentioned [in this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=macos#managing-icons-with-asset-catalogs), the problem might go away.

Comment: ToolmakerSteve, as mentioned in my original post, "I have an Assets.xcassets file for my actual app icons and they all work in the various iPhone and iPad emulators.". That was one of the first things I did when I created the project.

I'm certain the superfluous blank icons are being created during the build process but I can't figure out why. There is no reference to them in any setting or config file that I can find. I've looked everywhere.

Comment: At first I thought there was a filename requirement for items in Assets.xcassets, but I cannot find any docs that mention specific filenames for icons in Assets.xcassets. In any case, that does not explain why the build process generates blank icons.

Comment: This link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421511/xamarin-forms-ios-application-system-io-filenotfoundexception-while-debugging-on) may help you.

Comment: Wen xu Li - MSFT, that solution does not apply to my issue. I suspect my issue is related to Xcode since it is the build process that creates the blank icons.

Comment: 1. Check info.plist->Visual Assets->App Icons->Source to make sure it is your image collection. 2. Check in info.plist that the path under <key>XSAppIconAssets</key> is correct. 3. Make sure that the image format of your Assets is correct (conforms to the format and is a .png file).

Comment: Yes, all of those things are correct.

Comment: Try to create a new one in Assets, and then select the newly created name under the source of info.plist->Visual Assets.